# Using Command Line Arguments to Choose a Datatype?

Tags: c++, data-structures, command-line

Basically, based on whether a user inputs a 0 or 1 as a command line argument, I want my data class to either have a vector or an array (static) as its data member. I don't believe you can add if statements to .h files, but I'd like to do the following:

```
/*A.h*/
//various functions
private:
if(argv[1] == 0)
    vector b;
else if(argv[1] == 1)
    array b[10];
```

Is there a simple way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: This is an implementation question and should be asked at StackOverflow.SE.

Comment: There are different ways to achieve this, but the most simple one is to use a vector for both cases. You should explain why this is not sufficient for your case.

Answer (score 3):

C-type arrays and std::vector have very different interfaces, so even if you were able to do this, it would be tough to write meaningful code, as vector has push_back(), empty(), etc., and arrays do not.

What you are looking for is one object type with a consistent interface, that can have multiple implementations under-the-hood (it can be implemented using a C-style array, or a C++ standard vector). This is called *polymorphism* and a tutorial of how to achieve this with C++ can be found here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/

Comment: The linked sample code is missing a `virtual int area() = 0;`

Comment: @rwong It's not very good example, but the declaration for the virtual area function is found further down the page.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve that would be to use a template helper function. However note that this may lead to much code duplication if the code is complicated. But as I guess it's for something like performance measurement of different implementation methods (why else would the program user care how it is implemented), I guess that the code isn't too complicated anyway.

So for example:

```
template<typename type_to_use> int template_main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  type_to_use b;
  // ...
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argv[1]==0)
    template_main<vector>(argc, argv);
  else
    template_main<int[10]>(argc, argv);
}
```

Comment: What meaningful code could go into template_main? With the array, you can do something like `b[3] = 5` but with vector that will do bad things unless you do `b.reserve(3)` first. However, the array of course does not have a `reserve()` method, so that won't compile. You could pepper your code with checks to argv[1] to see what type you have, but that seems like a world of hurt. Without creating a common interface for the two data structures, I fail to see how this is a feasible solution.

Comment: You could use type traits and/or calls to overloaded functions to cover the differences. After initialization, both can be used with the `[]` syntax or in C++11 with the range based loop; otherwise, also getting start/end iterators (which for the array are pointers) can be done in helper functions.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a simple way to do this?

Yes: you create two different implementations with a common interface, defined by a base class. Then, you use a class factory to instantiate one of them, based on runtime parameters.

```
class data {
public:
    virtual ~data() = 0;
    // define public interface here
};

class vector_data: public data {
    std::vector<int> values;
public:
    // implement public interface here in terms of values
};

class array_data: public data {
    int values[20]; // or, std::array<int, 10> values;
public:
    // implement public interface here in terms of values
};

std::unique_ptr<data> make_data(bool vector_data)
{
    if(vector_data)
        return { new vector_data() };
    return { new array_data(); }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> args{ argv, argv + argc };
    auto data = make_data( args[1] == "vector" };
}
```

data will be instantiated to vector data only when you call:

```
> application.exe vector
```